# How to set textarea/input max length in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor I want to add the `maxlength` attribute to an `input` like

```
<textarea type="text" name="TheNameOfMyField" 
          class="TheNameOfMyClass" value="" rows="2" maxlength="255">
</textarea>
```

The component in Blazor is like this one

```
<InputTextArea @bind-Value="_model.ShortDescription" 
               class="form-control" id="gapShortDescription" />
```

and there is no options for maxlength or custom HTML attributes.

How can I do that?

Comment: Oh, I didn't. And, yes, it is working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These built-in components passthrough HTML attributes into the rendered output.  Therefore, you can just specify the HTML attributes exactly as you did for the `<textarea>` example.

(*Note*: converting my comment into an answer so we can wrap up this question)